# oscillator with opening price from a given time

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

[image: example]

I would like to draw an oscillator that will show on each interval less than 1 day the opening price at 16:00 from the VX1! contract on charts for other instruments, the code below shows different prices every 8 hours.

```
//@version=5

indicator("t2")
tzOffset = input.int(-1, 'UTC Offset')
VIX1 = request.security( "CBOE:VX1!", "360" , open,  gaps = barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off )


plot(VIX1, title="Price at 15:30 Oscillator", color=color.blue)
```

I tried different methods, entered parameters like hour=, minute=, but unfortunately, these functions didn't work for me :(

Comment: or how to change following code to plot same values also in different instruments ? by using request.security ? : //@version=5
indicator("t2")
var float open_price = na
is_start = (hour == 8) and (minute == 0)

open_price := is_start ? open : open_price
plot(open_price)

Comment: how do you plan get 16:00 time if you requesting timeframe = 360 min? The bar times will not be equal to hours, especially on this symbol

Answer (score 0):

if you want to recieve the opening price of the last bar of the session (which is 16:00 for this symbol), then:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

opPrice()=>
    ta.valuewhen(session.islastbar_regular, open, 0)

VIX1 = request.security("CBOE:VX1!", "60" , opPrice(), gaps = barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off)

plot(VIX1)
```